# Create array with uppercase ASCII letters in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way to create an array of uppercase ASCII letters like in python, where I can do

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

uppercase_letters = list(ascii_uppercase)
```

I don’t want to manually declare the array.

Comment: "_I don’t want to manually declare the array._" What are you ready to do ? There is not method ready for that.

Comment: I was wondering if there was

Comment: It ia literally one line of code, what a reason dont do it?

Comment: You can always "THISISAMESSAGE".toCharArray(); to get each character in that `String` in an array. Adding `toUppercase()` to be safe.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don’t want to manually declare the array" ? If you mean "is there a global constant/class/object existing that is an array of upper case ascii caracter in Java ?" then the answer is no

Comment: Should someone post an answer "No, there's no way" ?

Comment: @Aaron The code that I have posted in my answer could easily be put into a static method and called similarly to the Python code

Comment: There's ApacheCommons' CharSet that has a static fields which corresponds to the uppercase ASCII letter, however it's not iterable/indexable and its use seems limited to testing whether a string contains one character of a set of characters.

Comment: `ascii_uppercase` is just the string: `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`  that is declared on line 26 **[here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/87be28f4a1c5b76926c71a3d9f92503f9eb82d51/Lib/string.py)**

Answer (score 4):

It is a simple as

```
char [] chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chars));
```

**note**

Just because in Python you can do

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
```

doesn't mean that someone behind the scenes has not done something very similar to what I have done

Comment: So you want a **longer** way to do it?  As other your other comment *This seems more work than just manually declaring it*

Comment: We can quickly post a library that will do that if OP want... that way he will have to import our class and call `asciiUppercase()`...

Comment: @AxelH I agree - see my comment below the main question

Comment: @PearsonHardman `ascii_uppercase` is just the string: `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`  that is declared on line 26 **[here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/87be28f4a1c5b76926c71a3d9f92503f9eb82d51/Lib/string.py)** so @ScaryWombat 's answer is essentially identical to your python code.